# There's a way to embed a File to a Collection in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm working with MongoDb and I have this Model

```
public class Folder
    {

        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string  Description { get; set; }

}
```

so I need to attach Files to that Model (Folder). There's a way to do it without breaking the paradigm NoSQL?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a 16MB size limitation on a single document. If you really want to, checkout the manual on [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/).

That said, you're likely better off using the file system or a service like S3.